# bayes probability for consecutive tests

Tags: bayesian

Looking for some guidance for using Baysian probability for consecutive independent tests.

Using the traditional example of disease testing efficacy (say the 1% of the population are infected and the test is 95% accurate), I would like to understand the approach should a person chose to get a second test.

1. What is the probability of having the disease given both tests are positive?
2. What is the probability of having the disease if they get a different test and that test is only 90% accurate?

My intuition says that the first test result is not part of the input (prior) to the second test but I can't get it right in my head. For the second test, should I partition the sample space based on the probability of being infected based on the first test? =:-/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> My intuition says that the first test result is not part of the input (prior) to the second test but I can't get it right in my head. For the second test, should I partition the sample space based on the probability of being infected based on the first test? =:-/

The assumption should be that the two test results are *conditionally* independent when given the disease state of the same person. Otherwise, you cannot solve the problem.  So if we let the two test results be Bernoulli variables $T_1,T_2$, and disease state be $D$, then: $$\mathsf P(T_1{\,=\,}s,T_2{\,=\,}t\mid D{\,=\,}d)~=~\mathsf P(T_1{\,=\,}s\mid D{\,=\,}d)\,\mathsf P(T_2{\,=\,}t\mid D{\,=\,}d)$$

The rest is just the usual applications of Bayes' Theory and substitution for provided values.

> say the 1% of the population are infected and the test is 95% accurate)

That is $\mathsf P(D{\,=\,}1)=0.01$ and for each $k\in\{1,2\}$: $~\mathsf P(T_k{\,=\,}1\mid D{\,=\,}1)=0.95, \mathsf P(T_k{\,=\,}0\mid D{\,=\,}0)=0.95$.

> What is the probability of having the disease given both tests are positive?

$\mathsf P(D{\,=\,}1\mid T_1{\,=\,}1,T_2{\,=\,}1)$

> What is the probability of having the disease if they get a different test (*results*) and that test is only 90% accurate?

$\mathsf P(D{\,=\,}1\mid (T_1{\,=\,}1,T_2{\,=\,}0)\cup(T_1{\,=\,}0,T_2{\,=\,}1))$

Comment: Thanks. I see it now. I forgot about the fact it is a repeated trial of an independent test with only two possible outcomes. So hard to remember how to connect all these probability concepts! :-)
(Note: In your answer, the second case wasn't different test results, it was a completely different test provider that has a different test sensitivity. But I get your point.)

Comment: Actually, for the second case, is a Bernoulli trial the correct approach? In the second case the probability of the two outcomes is different. Shouldn't there be a different approach?

Comment: They are still conditionally independent Bernoulli variables, they are just not identically distributed.  All you have to do is adjust for the different success rate. @Bryon

Comment: So P(TaTb|D) will be P(Ta|D) x P(Tb|D) in both cases? 0.95^2 and 0.95x0.9?